# Biblatex "style" option not recognized when passed through a macro in a custom class

Tags: biblatex, document-classes, xkeyval

I'm porting my long preamble into a separate class file, and this is the only error left. In the MWE, I'm passing two key-value options to my class using xkeyval and feeding them to biblatex after combining them in a macro. This raises the error "Package xkeyval Error: `style' undefined in families`blx@opt@pre'." at biblatex.sty, 16186. Doing the same for the babel package doesn't result in any errors at all. I'm using LuaLaTeX, by the way.

Here's my MWE:

main.tex:

```
\documentclass{testclass}
\title{mwe}
\author{AdamantConlanger}
\date{October 2023}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

testclass.cls:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{testclass}[2023/10/20 Some Test Class]
\RequirePackage{xkeyval}

\newcommand{\mybibstyle}{}
\newcommand{\myotherbibargs}{}
\DeclareOptionX{bibstyle}[]{\renewcommand{\mybibstyle}{#1}}
\DeclareOptionX{otherbibargs}[]{\renewcommand{\myotherbibargs}{#1}}
\ExecuteOptionsX{bibstyle=phys, otherbibargs={sorting=nyt, giveninits=true}}
\ProcessOptionsX\relax

\newcommand{\mybibargs}{\myotherbibargs, style=\mybibstyle}
\LoadClass[titlepage, USenglish, 10pt, a4paper]{article}
\RequirePackage[\mybibargs]{biblatex}
```

Update: Thanks to David Carlisle, who suggested wrapping `\RequirePackage` in `\expandafter`, which fixed the MWE above. But it starts erroring again when I make the macro a bit more involved:

testclass.cls:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{testclass}[2023/10/20 Some Test Class]
\RequirePackage{xkeyval}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\mybibstyle}{}
\newcommand{\myotherbibargs}{}
\DeclareOptionX{bibstyle}[]{\renewcommand{\mybibstyle}{#1}}
\DeclareOptionX{otherbibargs}[]{\renewcommand{\myotherbibargs}{#1}}
\ExecuteOptionsX{bibstyle=phys, otherbibargs={sorting=nyt, giveninits=true}}
\ProcessOptionsX\relax

\newcommand{\mybibargs}{\expandafter\notblank\expandafter{\myotherbibargs}{\myotherbibargs, style=\mybibstyle}{style=\mybibstyle}}
\LoadClass[titlepage, USenglish, 10pt, a4paper]{article}
\expandafter\RequirePackage\expandafter[\mybibargs]{biblatex}
```

Comment: probably `\expandafter\RequirePackage\expandafter[\mybibargs]{biblatex}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle that works for the MWE, thanks! But it doesn't work when I expand the MWE, so I'll have to edit the question to account for that.

Comment: `\expanded{\noexpand\RequirePackage[\mybibargs]{biblatex}}`  would fully expand the options

Comment: that solved the problem entirely; thanks! I'll be closing the question now (if possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding David Carlisle's suggestion as an answer so I can close the question.

Simply using `\expanded{\noexpand\RequirePackage[\mybibargs]{biblatex}}` does indeed get rid of the error without any side effects (so far).